# 'return false' statement outside function error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jquery-isotope, jquery-cookie

I've been trying to implement the following Javascript code into the head of a Wordpress project. I found the original method here: [jQuery isotope query filtering results for url](http://www.mcnab.co/blog/content-management-systems/jquery-isotope-filtering-results-for-url/) but the last 'return false;' keeps throwing the error 'return not in function'. Admittedly, I had to update the script to use jQuery instead of the $'s in the original script & have included the jquery.cookie.js as they had it in their working example (as think it's old) but wondered if anyone could suggest a workaround for the return false error so I can get this concept to work with jQuery? Thanks

```js
<script>
// filter items when filter link is clicked
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  jQuery("#filters a").click(function(){
   var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
  jQuery('#portfolio').isotope({ filter: selector });
   return false;
  });
  });
</script>
<script>
  // Set cookie based on filter selector
  jQuery("#cookiefilter a").click(function(){
   var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
   $.cookie("listfilter", selector, { path: '/projects/' });
  }); 
  if ( $.cookie("listfilter") ) {
   jQuery('#portfolio').isotope({ filter: $.cookie("listfilter") });
   $.cookie("listfilter", null, { path: '/projects/' });
   return false;
  }
  
</script>
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 * jQuery Cookie plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Klaus Hartl (stilbuero.de)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 */
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
        options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
            options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Well the error is ok. The return shouldn't be there at all. Why do you need it there?

Comment: you dont need to include html, head or script tags to the post.

Comment: I have no idea why they originally used it. I just copied the JS verbatim & then had to change the $ to jQuery to get it to work. I thought the return had something to do with killing the cookie generated?

Comment: ..if I remove the last return false I then get an error: $ is undefined 'if ( $.cookie("listfilter") ) {'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct. Your "return false" occurs outside a function, which is not allowed.

```
<script>
    // Set cookie based on filter selector
    jQuery("#cookiefilter a").click(function(){
        var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
        $.cookie("listfilter", selector, { path: '/projects/' });
    });    /****END OF FUNCTION****/
```

The function() ends here. From here onwards, you are outside a function:

```
    if ( $.cookie("listfilter") ) {
        jQuery('#portfolio').isotope({ filter: $.cookie("listfilter") });
        $.cookie("listfilter", null, { path: '/projects/' });
        return false;
    }
```

Perhaps you ended the function early by mistake. 
If you move the line marked END OF FUNCTION to the end of that <script>, the error should be fixed.